# How to redact all IP addresses from a log file in Debian?

Tags: debian, logs, privacy

I have a pure-ftpd log file I would like to anonymize periodically. How would I go about doing this? I would like to strip IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. I'm afraid I do not know sed / awk.

The log file looks like this:

```
Oct  3 19:30:39 hostname pure-ftpd: (username@0.0.0.0) [INFO] New connection from 0.0.0.0
```

I would like to remove the `0.0.0.0` IP and replace it with something else. I know I will put the script into cron to run periodically.

Thanks!

Comment: I got IPV4, using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276822/replace-all-ip-addresses-in-a-file-to-a-specified-string. Anyone have any idea for IPV6?

Comment: See https://www.caida.org/tools/taxonomy/anonymization.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this for IPv4**:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/HELLO!/g' file
```

Replace `HELLO!` with what you need.

Example:

```
echo "Oct  3 19:30:39 hostname pure-ftpd: (username@0.0.0.0) [INFO] New connection from 0.0.0.0" | sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/HELLO!/g'
```

Output will:

```
Oct  3 19:30:39 hostname pure-ftpd: (username@HELLO!) [INFO] New connection from HELLO!
```

**With IPv6** everything is more complicated than it may seem. I need more examples of your log files to build correct regex pattern. But the simplest pattern for IPv6 replacing in your logs is:

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z0-9]*:\)\{1,7\}[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,4\}/HELLO!/2g' file
```

This pattern will replace most occurence of IPv6 addresses but not all! To replace all occurence you need more complex solution.

Example:

```
echo "Oct  3 19:30:39 hostname pure-ftpd: (username@2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348) [INFO] New connection from 2001:db8::1" | sed 's/\([A-Za-z0-9]*:\)\{1,7\}[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,4\}/HELLO!/2g'
```

Output will:

```
Oct  3 19:30:39 hostname pure-ftpd: (username@HELLO!) [INFO] New connection from HELLO!
```

---

See similar topics about IPv6 regex:

[Regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses)

Comment: It seems to miss IPv6 addresses in "ip a" output. Can you test/tweak please?